# Op-amp compensation terminated to negative supply voltage instead of ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, ground, high-frequency

I'm working on an amplifier for a SiPM and we are using the AD8099 amplifier in a transimpedance amplifier configuration.

I noticed that in the example circuits shown in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8099.pdf) the compensation capacitor connected to pin 5 is terminated at the negative supply voltage instead of ground. Why is this?

My only guess is that since the supply voltage is connected to ground via bypass capacitors close by and the compensation capacitor is only a few pF, it is identical to terminating to ground but slightly easier when doing PCB layout since there is one less via.

[image: ad8099 example circuit]

Comment: Here's a link to the evaluation board if you don't already have it. I might give some insight into this. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/ug-064.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> *Op-amp compensation terminated to negative supply voltage instead of
> ground*

It may or may not work effectively connected to ground.

It may be preferred (due to internal transistor positions) to be connected to the most negative rail. It might work connected to ground but you need to ensure that supply decoupling capacitors (from ground to the negative rail) do not become inductive below around 500 MHz. This latter point is quite hard to achieve unless you use a 10 pF (or less) decoupler but, if you do, you'll have an extra capacitor and this kind of misses the point of what you are trying to do.

I suggest you look at capacitors and see how a lot of capacitors above 1 nF are quite resonant in the 10 MHz to 100 MHz range.

Answer (score 1):

Op-amps do not have an internal ground connection. The internal circuit is bound within the Vs+ and Vs- rails so compensation is more effective to one of the rails.

Some op-amps have a pair of connections brought externally for compensation between points within a circuit.

The data sheet does not provide a glimpse inside so nothing can be determined for this device in particular.

The ground is used to provide a convenient reference for connection to the external circuitry.